# Custom URL Scheme not a link in Outlook (iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, outlook, mobile-application

Our app can be started with a custom URL Scheme like `myapp://mainpage?param=123`. This works when it is included as a link in a web page. And, on iOS, it works in the mail client that comes with the platform.

After a user registered and installed the app, he receives a mail with a link. We need this because we want to pass some data into the app.

However, this doesn't work in the Microsoft Outlook app on iOS.

On Android, as a work-around, our app also supports a https URL Scheme like `https://myapp/mainpage?param=123`

Does anyone know how to start my app from a mail in Microsoft Outlook on iOS?

If not needed, I prefer not to depend on a third-party website. Universal links won't work, because the app works together with a site that is on a separate url for each of our business customers.

This is the part from how I registered the scheme in my `Info.plist`:

```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>My App</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>myapp</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Comment: Does `https://myapp/mainpage?param=123` work with Outlook? Does any url work with Outlook? If you can get a url to work in Outlook, but isn't the way you'd prefer to use, you can create a `if` statement specifically for Outlook, which will not be seen by Android or IOS. You can do the same thing specifically for IOS.

Comment: @gwally I don't understand, where could I create the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

iOS too supports Universal links.
So, Instead of using custom scheme implement [Universal link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in iOS too.

It's an old repo, but might be helpful github.com/Satish/iOS-Universal-Links

You need to host apple-app-site-association at http://your-site.com/ domain (ie. http://your-site.com/apple-app-site-association).

```
 {
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "XXXX.nnnn",
                "paths": [
                    "/yourpath"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

You can host this file on a single domain and send a URL with same domain `http://your-site.com` and send an identifier as a param to identify your business and take action in your app code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd rather not host a new site with the sole purpose for handling app links.

Answer (score 0):

In email, we can hide content to a degree depending on the email client.

If you add this to your style sheet:

```
<style>
  .android {display: block;}
  .webkit {display: none;}

  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .android {display: none;}
    .webkit {display: block !important;}
  }
</style>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 <style type="text/css">
   .android {display: none;}
   .webkit {display: none;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This tells the email client if it's android or any email client, display the class `.android` The media query tells all webkit clients (Apple Mail, IOS) to hide android and display the webkit link.

`<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>` creates a special style sheet to hide `.android` and `.webkit` classes from Outlook.

In the body of the email, do this:

```
<!--[if mso | IE]>
  Outlook Only: url://that-works-with-outlook
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
  <span class="android">All Email Clients: https://myapp/mainpage?param=123</span>
  <span class="webkit" style="display: none;">Webkit-only: myapp://mainpage?param=123</span>
<![endif]-->
```

`<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->` hides the Apple and other device urls from Outlook so they do not display in Outlook in your email.

`<!--[if mso | IE]>` hides Outlook-only urls from non Outlook clients.

`.webkit` class hides the Apple / IOS link from other clients.

`.android` hides the url that works for other clients from Outlook.

This way you can target Outlook, Apple and works for all other email clients without confusion to the end-user.

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/w4z8tp8g/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! The problem however persists: the Outlook Mail App doesn't show the links with the custom URL Scheme. What I'm gone do is: in the mail point the user to a site which displays the link with the custom URL Scheme.

Comment: @JaccoDieleman I'm not sure what url scheme works for you with Outlook. I'm just giving you a way to target Outlook, Android and IOS with the URLs that work for your task.