# Is there a way to get app id for an Enterprise app that is in AppCenter only?

Tags: android, ios, outlook, visual-studio-app-center, appsflyer

I am currently trying to integrate deeplinking through a service called AppsFlyer and on their page, they mentioned requiring an app id - which can be found on Apple App Store/Google Play Store or Microsoft Phone App Store.

I'm not sure if AppCenter has such information available or how to even retrieve it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Appsflyer wants to direct the user to the App Store to install the app if they don't already have it. To do so they need the id from the App Store. You can't use appsflyer to install an app that doesn't come from the App Store.

Comment: Do you really need appsflyer for a non-AppStore app?

Comment: hi no not really. Actually, I developed a custom implementation which worked for browser email clients and iPhone native mail clients. For some reason, the Outlook App on phones doesn't allow deeplinks to be clicked (i.e <a href='myapp://verifyemail' </a>)

Comment: also I am using SendGrid to send the email. Apparantly SendGrid also wraps a wrapper around the href - for click tracking. I think a simple solution is needed here, maybe a native implementation or a lib like nodemailer

Comment: I don't think universal links really work for enterprise signed apps. If you know the app is installed you can just bounce through a web server that redirects to the myApp url

Comment: yup thats what I did. user clicks link on email -> directs to web server -> onpageload execute javascript to redirect to installed app -> redirected.

This worked for browser outlook and mail app but not for native Outlook app. For the Outlook app, it simply didn't redirect the user.

Comment: It may just be a problem with Outlook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211122/custom-url-scheme-not-a-link-in-outlook-ios-android not opening URL scheme links

Comment: yes guess I have to do it the hard way which is to use some 3rd party provider

Comment: You don't need a 3rd party provider. You can just create your own universal links by putting an Apple-site-association file in place on your webserver linked to your bundle id.

Comment: Ok thanks that worked - I used S3/Cloudfront. Is it possible to pass in query parameters into deep links and have it read by the app ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the AppStore ID right?

When you open the AppStore from any browser and click on the App you want the Id from you already have the ID. The Id is saved inside the url.

If you need more information check out this link
[Finding your App Store ID](https://learn.apptentive.com/knowledge-base/finding-your-app-store-id/#:%7E:text=App%20Settings%20screen.-,iOS,id284708449%20the%20ID%20is%3A%20284708449%20.)

[image]

Comment: yes for Apple app store, but mine is microsoft AppCenter which I dont think provides this info